# Is including a Default Constructors good practice to include, for a class with overloaded constructors.

Tags: java, default-constructor

In Java, when a constructor is overloaded, the Default Constructor is not automatically included. While for compilation a Default Constructor is not required, I have read that it is good practice to include a Default Constructor along with the overloaded constructors.

Is this common professional practice or a few programmers option?

Comment: To be able to answer it would be a good idea if you told us what *language* you are wondering about. Please edit your question to include the correct language tag. Or add the tag `language-agnostic` if it doesn't matter (though that will make the question to broad and will get it closed).

Comment: Thank you, I have formatted the question.

Answer (score 0):

A default (no-argument) constructor is automatically created only when you do not define any constructor yourself.

If you need two constructors, one with arguments and one without, you need to manually define both.

Comment: That is true, but I am curious to why adding a default, even if you don't use it good practice as a developer.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends; while it is common for DTOs to always have a default constructor (so that they adhere to Javabeans convention), if the constructor argument is a mandatory dependency (think a data access component in a service bean) it should be in every constructor, thus making the default constructor a bad choice.